# Providing different MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, phpunit

I want to check if a method executing some SQL queries return expected results, based on different data in the tables - how can I do this?

I have the following test:

```
<?php

class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
{

    public function getConnection()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test.database', 'root', 'root');
        return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo);
    }

    public function getDataSet()
    {
        return $this->createMySQLXMLDataSet(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../data.xml');
    }

    public function testGetActiveCollection()
    {
        $cdm = new FooDataMapper();
        $fooCollection = $cdm -> getActiveCollection();
        $this -> assertGreaterThan(0, sizeof($fooCollection -> getAll()));
    }

}
```

It works - I exported production database and imported it into test database. But I only have one dataset this way, I can't check what happens if there are no rows in the table, or if the table contains different rows, etc.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: it's a little unclear what you are asking. Why not use your test database to simulate the extra conditions you mention?

Comment: Install the MySql workbench https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ It's like SQL Server Management Studio, but for MySql. ***NOTE: If the link changes then hunt for MySQL Workbench in your favourite internet search utility. The first port of call is bound to be the official MySQL website, which is currently www.mysql.com***